# $(window).scroll not fast enough to process my jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-waypoints

Im having an issue with window scrolling where I think events are firing too quickly to process.

Im using waypoints to detect when a subnav on my page hits the header when scrolling, and when it does it pushes the header up off the page. And when scrolling back up, the header gets pulled down into its original position. Now the first part works flawlessly, the head gets pushed up, but pulling it back down is very buggy. Scrolling too quickly results in the header getting stuck on the way.

It gets stuck like this:
[image]
But it should be down further:
[image]

It will work if you scroll slowly, but realistically its not cutting it. Unfortunately the site is not yet public so I cant link to it just yet.

```
        $('.subnav-wrapper').waypoint(function(direction) {
            var $headerWrapper = $('.header-wrapper');
            var headerHeight = $headerWrapper.outerHeight();

            $(window).scroll(function() { 
                var scrollHeight = $(this).scrollTop();

                if( scrollHeight >= 400 ) {
                     $headerWrapper.css( 'margin-top', ( scrollHeight - 400 ) * -1 );
                }
            });

        },
        {
            offset: $('.header-wrapper').outerHeight()
        });
```

Comment: Just wondering why are you nesting scroll event declaration inside waypoints callback? Here, each time the waypoints event is fired, you are adding a new onscroll event for the window. And as waypoints get fired when you scroll window, this could be really buggy i guess. You could check how many onscroll event get bound using in your console: `$._data(window,'events').scroll`

Answer (score 2):

Move the `.scroll` declaration outside the waypoint declaration.

Then use [lodash `.throttle`](http://lodash.com/docs#throttle) to limit the number of executions. Also, lets cache the jQuery window object.

```
 var $window = $(window);
 $window.scroll(_.throttle(function () {
   var scrollHeight = $window.scrollTop();
   if (scrollHeight >= 400) {
     $headerWrapper.css('margin-top', (scrollHeight - 400) * -1);
   }
 }, 16), {
   trailing: true
 });
```

Limiting to 16ms is a good rule of thumb because its the refresh rate of a 60hz monitor, and users wont notice anything faster than 16ms anyway.

Comment: seems good but you don't really need to use the throttle method, only using a basic logic with a clearTimeout()/setTimeout() will be enough. Anyway +1

Comment: The good thing about `_.throttle` is its super reliable and readable, but more so its the `trailing : true` part is a real benefit.

Comment: Ya looks like a good plugin. Oh i see, it is underscore kind of extension, right?!

Comment: I just included that plugin but Im getting the error:  `i.handler.apply is not a function` Ill play around and see if I can get it working though.

Comment: I just tried the throttle/debounce plugin with at 16ms throttle and that didnt work either. The JS ran, but the header still sticks when scrolling down too quickly.

Comment: @rugbert, in that case is a logic bug, not an over firing problem