# Effectively detecting an elements current position from the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

The goal of my project is for vertical scrolling to become impossible once a specific element reaches the top of the window, then the content in that element would scroll horizontally, and then it would resume vertical scrolling once the horizontal scroll has reached the end. Here I am simply attempting to make the first part a reality (making vertical scrolling impossible once a specific element reaches the top of the window). However, I am having trouble effectively detecting an element’s scroll position from the top of the window. I have determined how to get an elements current distance from the top of the window and checking its current distance using the scroll event, but the scroll event does not seem to be firing fast enough. If I scroll slowly, it works as expected but if I scroll too quickly, it detects the distance of the element from the top of the window as being “<= 0” too late and the removal of vertical scroll happens when the element is already past the top of the window. The only thing I can think of would be to increase the frequency at which it checks the element’s current distance from the top of the window but that could end up taking up a lot of processing power. Below you will find my Javascript and a link my Codepen. If any of you have a solution to this or even an entirely different approach to achieve my goal, it would be very much appreciated!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/robertDD/pen/wvaJRYX

Javascript

```
  $(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var sliderPosCurr = $("#slider-wrap").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(); // current position of top of slider from top of window

    if (sliderPosCurr <= 0) {
      $("html").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
    }

  });
```

Comment: you can use this api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API to effectively detect an element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21005704/9357872

Comment: Thanks for the api suggestion @AngelSalazar but I tried to implement it and I'm having the same issue of scrolling too fast causing it to not work. Can you take look at this second pen? https://codepen.io/robertDD/pen/RwPpvMe